# Does Archiving always do a full rebuild of all targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I've been trying different settings to get my iOS project to archive successfully. I have a library target with 60 source files and an application target with 4, with a dependency on the library.
It seems Archiving always builds for all architectures, regardless of "only build active architecture" setting, which means since I build for armv7, armv7 & arm64 I've ~200 files to compile.
It also seems Archiving always builds every file, is that right? I just archived my library target separately as I was trying to fix a problem, and now when I archive the application target it immediately starts rebuilding the library even though it just built it seconds ago.

Is this just part of the nature of archiving, that it always rebuilds everything from scratch for every architecture, to try and ensure no mistakes?

Comment: have you solved it? I am using command line `xcodebuild archive` and faces the same problem (xcode 8.1.2)